# In the php, how can I have a category of a custom post type display?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, categories, search

It's for my search page on my site. I would link it but it's not up and running yet so hopefully, I can explain.

I have custom post types that are then broken out into categories. I want, when searching the site, the results to list what category that type of content is (the content is classified as custom post type "library").

How do I write this?

Comment: Just for clarification, are you just looking to echo out the categories when you output the rest of the content for each of the CPT entries being loaded?

Comment: @TonyDjukic , sorry I'm new to this and still learning! So I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I'm trying to set it up so that when you search the website, the search results display the title of the post as well as what type of content it is (the custom post type).

Comment: Ok, so you want to list the post type name along with the title of the entry on the search results page, not the category taxonomy?